# Generating alerts from ossec ( server- agent ) model

Tags: ubuntu, ossec

I'm very new to OSSEC. I use a server-agent model. I wish to generate alert for the following actions ( in agent side ):

1) Sample Alert for delation of logs

I added the rules for these in agent's `ossec.conf` using `<localfile>` tags. Like this :

```
  <localfile>
    <log_format>syslog</log_format>
    <location>/var/log/syslog</location>
  </localfile>
```

In my server's ossec.conf. I added the following :

```
<global>
    <email_notification>yes</email_notification>
    <email_to>xxxx@xxxxxx</email_to>
    <smtp_server>smtp.gmail.com</smtp_server>
    <email_from>xxxx@xxx</email_from>
  </global>
```

And I restarted my server. Now I tried to delete the agents syslog file using `rm syslog`. But no alerts has been triggered.

Where I'm making the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`localfile`](http://www.ossec.net/doc/manual/monitoring/index.html) is different from [`syscheck`](http://www.ossec.net/doc/manual/syscheck/index.html).

Open the `/var/ossec/rules/syslog_rules.xml`, you will see a bad words list:

`<var name="BAD_WORDS">core_dumped|failure|error|attack|bad |illegal |denied|refused|unauthorized|fatal|failed|Segmentation Fault|Corrupted|unresolved|Down</var>`

Using [logger](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_logger.htm) command to creates an entry in system log:

```
$ logger connection failed
```

you can see this message in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Aug 28 17:12:41 ubuntu quanta: connection failed
```

and get an email with following content:

```
OSSEC HIDS Notification.
2012 Aug 28 17:12:32

Received From: (Nagios_Slave_6.142) 192.168.6.142->/var/log/messages
Rule: 1002 fired (level 2) -> "Unknown problem somewhere in the system."
Portion of the log(s):

    Aug 28 17:12:21 ubuntu quanta: connection failed



 --END OF NOTIFICATION
```

Comment: Oh! So I added like this `<directories check_all="yes">/var/log</directories>` to `syscheck`(in my agent side). I even did this `logger` command, which also working. But email is not triggered. I'm using here google's smtp server. Can you show me how you have configured your servers `<email>` settings?

Comment: Change the smtp server to `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com` and try again. If it doesn't work, change to `127.0.0.1` and take a look at [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-use-gmail-as-a-smarthost.html).

Comment: Cool that works. But I have a doubt. I specified the `syscheck` in my agent side. With the rule `<directories check_all="yes">/var/log</directories>`. So that means when I do `logger connection failed` I need to be alerted. But I didn't. I restarted my server, in this case a alert is generated stating that my server is started. But changing the `syslog` with `logger` doesn't seemed to be generating an alert.

Comment: Dont' do that. You probably want to check integrity for only configuration files in `/etc`.

Comment: But my boss wants me to generate an alert for `Logs for New user creation`, `Sample Alert for delation of logs`, `wrong password alert log`. So I'm doing that. So adding `<directories check_all="yes">/var/log</directories>` in the `syscheck` is correct, as far these req concerned?

Comment: You're doing wrong. Logs analysis should be place in `localfile` section, not `syscheck` (for integrity checking). By default, OSSEC has rules to detect some common actions by analysing important logs. For the particular pattern/action, write your own [rule](http://www.ossec.net/doc/manual/rules-decoders/create-custom.html).

Comment: Thanks! It is working now.. But I have my last doubt. Putting the required log files into `localfile` and making them fail will generate the alerts right? And also what is the rules for `localfile`?

Comment: _Putting the required log files into localfile and making them fail will generate the alerts right?_ --> Yes, if the default rules contain your 'fail' pattern. _And also what is the rules for localfile?_ --> what do you mean?

Comment: For now I haven't specified any rules. But I'm following the format of `syslog` for monitoring my log files via `localfile`.